# Make string with Promises in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question with promises in Node JS.
I need to make a JSON string with some data coming from two promises, but it does not make right. This is my code:

```
var aux = "{";

geocoder.reverse(initPointReversing)
  .then(function(initData) {
    aux += "originAddress:'" + initData[0].formattedAddress + "',";
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });

geocoder.reverse(endPointReversing)
  .then(function(endData) {
    aux += "destinationAddress:'" + endData[0].formattedAddress + "',";
  })
  .catch(function(err2) {
    console.log(err2);
  });

aux += "}";
```

Inside the promises. the strings have value, but outside, the result it's only `"{}"`

How can I need to use these promises correctly?

Comment: you need to wait for asynchronous code to complete

Comment: Rather than create a JSON string manually, it will probably be much easier to create an object which has the properties you want, and then call `JSON.stringify` in order to make sure everything gets formatted properly. Your current code doesn't escape quotes.

Comment: The JSON string is only an example, I looking to learn how does the promises work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to use Promise.all

```
var p1 = geocoder.reverse(initPointReversing)
.then(function(initData) {
    return initData[0].formattedAddress;
});

var p2 = geocoder.reverse(endPointReversing)
.then(function(endData) {
    return endData[0].formattedAddress;
});

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(function(results) {
    var t = {originAddress: results[0], destinationAddress: results[1]};
    var aux = JSON.stringify(t);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If you're using the latest node,

```
var p1 = geocoder.reverse(initPointReversing).then(initData => initData[0].formattedAddress);
var p2 = geocoder.reverse(endPointReversing).then(endData => endData[0].formattedAddress);

Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(([originAddress, destinationAddress]) => {}
    var aux = JSON.stringify({originAddress, destinationAddress});
    // do things
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Promise.all([geocoder.reverse(initPointReversing),geocoder.reverse(endPointReversing)])
.then(function(values) {
    aux = "{";
    aux += "originAddress:'" + values[0][0].formattedAddress + "',";
    aux += "destinationAddress:'" + values[1][0].formattedAddress + "',";
    aux = "}";
})
.catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

How to use `Promise.all`, you can look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)